# Get value of Label in ASP.NET website from C# windows form application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing web browser in `C# windows form application` using WebBrowser component.And also a website in ASP.NET using C#.Both are different projects.How can i use `value of Label` from windows form application and use the same value in ASP.NET website?
Help me !
Thanks in advance !!

Comment: The HtmlAgilityPack could be useful to parse your page.

Comment: Why do you want to use the value of a label from windows form application in your ASP.NET website? What is it for?

Comment: Label is username and this value i need in website to insert details of that particular username(cant tell u detail flow,its a complex project)

Answer (score 0):

Did you know you can write code to automate browsers, such as IE or Firefox? I mean, write code to launch a browser window, load pages at will, easily access particular parts of web pages, simulate user input (textboxes, controls, buttons, etc). It's commonly used to automate testing of web pages, and what-not.

There are multiple libraries out there, but I personally tried WatIn: http://watin.org/. Open source (free), .net component, easy to use, ton of examples.

I'm suggesting this as an alternative - if it fits your model. I know this doesn't answer your question; sorry.